# VBA Print Outlook Item

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to print an Outlook mailitem and attachment to pdf files.

I could manually select the attachments, and click quick print, but I don't know how to achieve this using VBA.

I am trying to save the attachments to disk, but, I can't find a way to print the saved files, since the attachments could be any file type like word, excel, and images.

I got the code below to print, but there is no way to specify the file path for printed files.

```
Sub PrintAttachments(objMail As Outlook.MailItem, savedPath As String)
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim filePath As String
                Set xShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        Set xNameSpace = xShellApp.Namespace(0)
    If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For x = 1 To objMail.Attachments.Count
            Set objAttachment = objMail.Attachments.Item(x)
            filePath = savedPath & objAttachment.fileName
            objAttachment.SaveAsFile filePath
            Set xNameSpaceItem = xNameSpace.ParseName(filePath)

            xNameSpaceItem.InvokeVerbEx ("print")
        Next x
    End If
End Sub
```

Update:

Is there any way to achieve the following function programmably?

Outlook -> Print -> Microsoft Print to PDF -> Print Options -> Print attached files.

Comment: You have filepath variable, use the to set the path. Are trying to print and save it pdf?

Comment: @0m3r I am trying to save it as pdf and call printer to print, how to specify the path in `InvokeVerbEx`?

Comment: and what type of attachment are you trying to print?

Comment: @0m3r Excel, Word, image and etc. Is there any way to configure the `Microsoft Print to PDF Print Options` from vba?